# .htaccess multiple rewrites in the same directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

To remove ".php" extensions, and it works great. I have been playing around with adding another rules, however it gets ignored. I need a second rule to say:

example.php/"variable" then sub it with example.php?page=variable

URL the user sees:

example.com/folder/example/variable

Actual page is example.com/folder/example?page=variable

I have a basic understanding of the rewrite engine, but I'm no expert. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another condition to your php rule, one that checks if the rewrite destination actually exists. Afte rthat, you want pretty much the same thing but you check for the path info:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/([^/]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm still getting a 500 error with this. Would I need to change anything?

Comment: @user2861406 See the edit to the 3rd condition of the first rule